# access control within items control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, itemscontrol, itemcontainergenerator

this is my `itemsControl` :

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MessagesContainer">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageText}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageCreatedDate}" />
                    </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

i want to access top 3 items (ie. top 3 stackPanels) to change their background color, so i tried `ItemContainerGenerator`  below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
   UIElement uiElement = 
    (UIElement)MessagesContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);//<-- always null
}
```

but `uiElement` always having `null` value Whereas my itemsControl binding well
any ideas ? or any other way to get specific items from `itemsControl` ?

Comment: Not really answering the question, but you'd save yourself much pain if you binded the Background property of your stackpanel to a property of your model

Comment: @KooKiz not really understand what r u trying to say ?

Comment: Add a Background property to the object you're binding to the ItemsControl, then use it to change the background at will: `<StackPanel Background="{Binding Path=Background}"> ...`